# How do I #include plugin source files in my custom Unreal Engine module?

Tags: c++, ios, augmented-reality, unreal-engine4

I'm working with a C++ Unreal Engine project and made my own custom module called MyActor, Unreal Engine automatically created the .cpp and .h files for me. That much appears to be working.

So now I want to include classes or methods from the AppleARKit plugin then override and call them from my custom MyActor module.

First I tried using `#include AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h` because it has the`IARKitBlendShapePublisher::PublishBlendshapes` method which I want to modify and use.

It didn't work at first with this error: `E1696 Cannot open source file AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h` but I found out I could include them in Visual Studio using the "Include Directories" under Properties like this:
[image]

The `AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h` lives in the Public folder but I included the Private folder as well, I don't know if I need to do that. This appeared to work at first but then I got the same error as before for every dependency inside the `AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h` file.

Do I have to include the individual directories for every dependency down the entire chain? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I ran into the issue of including files from a plugin, in my case LidarPointCloud, the following steps worked for me:

1) In my `<project-name>.Build.cs` file, I added the module name I wished to use (LidarPointCloudRuntime) to the public dependency list

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "LidarPointCloudRuntime", "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });
```

I determined the module name by opening the `.uplugin` file in the plugin's folder, and looked at the `Modules` section. If multiple module names are listed, you should pick the one that contains the source for the classes you care about.

2)  I then rebuilt the project, closed my editor, then right clicked my `<project-name>.uproject` file and regenerated project files.

After that, I was able to access the .h files in my code.

-Update-

It seems that `AppleARKitFaceSupport` has dependencies on other plugins that may need to be included. For example, `ARSystems.h` lives in `AugmentedReality`. When I add that to `PublicDependencyModuleNames` and perform the same steps, it can find `ARSystem.h`.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions:
1. found the module name and added it to my build.cs. "AppleARKitFaceSupport".

2. Ran "Build Solution" in Visual Studio. Closed Visual Studio, and ran "Generate Visual Studio Project Files" on my <project-name>.uproject file.

3. Then I added #include "AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h" in my MyActor.cpp file. But then I got an error for every dependency of the AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory.h

E1696 cannot open source file "ARSystem.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "ARTrackable.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "ILiveLinkSource.h"
etc...

Comment: @Purp Please see my update. Dependencies may need to be included.

Comment: @V Money Thank you so much, this worked. I no longer have the errors. I ended up adding "AugmentedReality" and "LiveLinkInterface" to the PublicDependencyModuleNames .